# Sqoop hive import from oozie

Tags: hive, oozie, sqoop

I am using Cloudera Quick Start Docker image

The quickstart image has mysql installed in it. When i use following sqoop command from command line to import categories table it works and i can see that categories table is created

```html
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db --username root --password cloudera -m 1 --table categories --hive-import --hive-overwrite
```

Then i logged into Hue as cloudera user and i did create a new oozie workflow with single sqoop task, but when i try to execute that sqoop is able to download the data into HDFS, but when it tries to create hive table on top of that it fails

This is how my workflow.xml looks like

```html
<workflow-app name="My_Workflow" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5" xmlns:sla="uri:oozie:sla:0.2">
    <start to="sqoop-4467"/>
    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <action name="sqoop-4467">
        <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <command>import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db --username root --password cloudera -m 1 --table categories --hive-import --hive-overwrite
</command>
        </sqoop>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
          <sla:info>
            <sla:nominal-time>${nominal_time}</sla:nominal-time>
            <sla:should-end>${30 * MINUTES}</sla:should-end>
          </sla:info>
    </action>
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

This is how my job.properties file looks like

```html
oozie.use.system.libpath=True
security_enabled=False
dryrun=False
nameNode=hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020
nominal_time=2016-12-20T20:53Z
jobTracker=quickstart.cloudera:8032
```

After the job failed, when i checked the /user/home/cloudera folder i can see the categories folder with data but i dont see the hive table being created. This is the error that i see in the jobhistory server for the failed job

```html
Sqoop command arguments :
             import
             --connect
             jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db
             --username
             root
             --password
             cloudera
             -m
             1
             --table
             categories
             --hive-import
             --hive-overwrite
Fetching child yarn jobs
tag id : oozie-3ff81b7743470e73dcb44de6729a66d9
Child yarn jobs are found - 
=================================================================

>>> Invoking Sqoop command line now >>>

6223 [uber-SubtaskRunner] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.tool.SqoopTool  - $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.
6302 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop  - Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.7.0
6336 [uber-SubtaskRunner] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool  - Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
6336 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool  - Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
6336 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool  - delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
6367 [uber-SubtaskRunner] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory  - $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.
6654 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager  - Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
6666 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool  - Beginning code generation
7250 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `categories` AS t LIMIT 1
7279 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `categories` AS t LIMIT 1
7281 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.orm.CompilationManager  - HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
9303 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.orm.CompilationManager  - Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-yarn/compile/4fd8773510dfe4082d136b2ab7d27eb3/categories.jar
9314 [uber-SubtaskRunner] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager  - It looks like you are importing from mysql.
9314 [uber-SubtaskRunner] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager  - This transfer can be faster! Use the --direct
9314 [uber-SubtaskRunner] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager  - option to exercise a MySQL-specific fast path.
9314 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager  - Setting zero DATETIME behavior to convertToNull (mysql)
9318 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase  - Beginning import of categories
9388 [uber-SubtaskRunner] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.JobBase  - SQOOP_HOME is unset. May not be able to find all job dependencies.
10238 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat  - Using read commited transaction isolation
29055 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase  - Transferred 1.0049 KB in 19.659 seconds (52.3425 bytes/sec)
29061 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase  - Retrieved 58 records.
29076 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `categories` AS t LIMIT 1
29097 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  - Loading uploaded data into Hive
Intercepting System.exit(1)

<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]

Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully

Oozie Launcher, uploading action data to HDFS sequence file: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/oozie-oozi/0000012-161221020706124-oozie-oozi-W/sqoop-4467--sqoop/action-data.seq

Oozie Launcher ends
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you copy the hive-site.xml to HDFS ?that will do or you can import the table to hdfs path using --target-dir and set the location of hive table to point that path

Comment: where in hdfs ?

Comment: copy it somewhere and mention the hdfs path in workflow.xml as <file>hdfspath/hive-site.xml#hive.site.xml</file

Comment: specifying hdfs path and pointing hive table to that location is easier as you might find trouble locating the correct hive=site.xml if you are using hortonworks